# No module named 'ldap' has been installed on simplesamlphp

Tags: php, ldap, simplesamlphp

```
SimpleSAML\Error\Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION
    Backtrace:
    2 www/_include.php:17 (SimpleSAML_exception_handler)
    1 vendor/symfony/error-handler/ErrorHandler.php:607 (Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler::handleException)
    0 [builtin] (N/A)
    Caused by: Exception: No module named 'ldap' has been installed.
    Backtrace:
    8 lib/SimpleSAML/Module.php:427 (SimpleSAML\Module::resolveClass)
    7 lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Source.php:315 (SimpleSAML\Auth\Source::parseAuthSource)
    6 lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Source.php:358 (SimpleSAML\Auth\Source::getById)
    5 lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Simple.php:68 (SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple::getAuthSource)
    4 lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Simple.php:167 (SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple::login)
    3 [builtin] (call_user_func_array)
    2 lib/SimpleSAML/HTTP/RunnableResponse.php:72 (SimpleSAML\HTTP\RunnableResponse::sendContent)
    1 vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php:394 (Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::send)
    0 www/module.php:10 (N/A)
```

I am trying to configure simplesamlphp for ldap authentication, and getting the error above. I installed and enabled php ldap module.
[image]

I also set referrals to false in `/config/authsources.php` because I am trying to connect an AD Controller.

My server configurations are;

- Ubuntu 20.04 server
- SimpleSAMLphp 1.19.1
- PHP 7.4.3

Answer (score 2):

You also need to install and enable the SSP ldap module.

To enable an installed module
`touch $SSP_INSTALL/module/ldap/enable`

If SSP ldap module is not installed, I believe you can do `composer require simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp-module-ldap`

Comment: I created the "enable" file. No change. I also ran composer require. Still same.